# Python filter() not working and returning TypeError?

Tags: python, typeerror

I have written a prime generator program that generates all the primes in some range. the code is below:

```
from math import sqrt

primes = range(3, 31623, 2)

for i in range(len(primes)):
    if primes[i] != None:
        if primes[i] >= sqrt(31622):
            break
        for x in range(i+1, len(primes)):
            if primes[x] and not primes[x] % primes[i]:
                primes[x] = None

primes = [x for x in primes if x]

def is_prime(x):
    #if x <= 31623 and x in primes:
        #return True
    if x % 10 == 5 or not x % 10 or not x % 2:
        return False
    else:
        for i in primes:
            if not x % i or i >= sqrt(x):
                return False
    return True


l = [x for x in range(999900001, 1000000000, 2) if is_prime(x)]
#l = filter(is_prime(x), range(999900001, 1000000000, 2))
print l
```

The problem is in the last couple lines. If I use the list comprehension, everything works fine. However, if I try to create the list of primes using filter(), Python returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "primes.py", line 29, in <module>
    l = filter(is_prime(x), range(999900001, 1000000000, 2))
  File "primes.py", line 20, in is_prime
    if x % 10 == 5 or not x % 10 or not x % 2:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Can someone please tell me where the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just pass the function to `filter`, not call the function and pass its result. Example -

```
l = filter(is_prime, range(999900001, 1000000000, 2))
```

---

The issue most probably occurs because x is defined as None , most probably due to the list comprehension -

```
primes = [x for x in primes if x]
```

Then, when you do -

```
l = filter(is_prime(x), range(999900001, 1000000000, 2))
```

It first evaluates `is_prime(x)` (for x as `None`) , which is causing the issue. What you actually need to do is the send the function as the first argument (not evaluate it for x).

Comment: Thanks, all the documentation showed examples with lambda so that's why i got confused